# How do I delete a character in a text file without manipulating the rest of the data in the file?

Tags: file, text, fstream, random-access

How do I delete a character in a text file without manipulating the rest of the data in the file? For example, *file.txt* has `1234567` and I want to delete the `6` so *file.txt* contains `123457` without reading the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done. You cannot delete a character without processing the remaining suffix of the file to close the gap.

The underlying data structures of most mainstream file systems do not support a constant-time delete of an arbitrary range of bytes, or individual bytes.

It's not only a matter of file system structure. Deleting bytes without moving any data would cause a misalignment between file blocks and memory pages. This has implications for buffering, caching and memory mapping.

Comment: Is there a way just to delete the last character ?

Comment: @Need_Help This won't really do what you want in most cases, but you can certainly *truncate* a file. For example, to delete the last character plus trailing newline:  `File.truncate 'file', File.size('file') - 2`.

Comment: @Need_Help There may be. Mainstream operating systems have ways to truncate a file to a given length. POSIX systems have the `truncate` and `ftruncate` library functions.  In the Windows API, the function `SetFilePointer` to seek to a position in a file, and `SetEndOfFile` to truncate the file after that position.

Comment: @CodeGnome Not sure what language you're using there; the only clue is that `fstream` is among the tags, suggesting C++.

Comment: @Kaz My examples are in Ruby. I have no interest in playing "guess my language/implementation" with the OP. The point about truncation is generally going to be valid in any modern language, but I agree I should have mentioned the language of my comment's example in the event that someone deep-linked to that one comment without reading the rest of the page for context.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

You can't generally read text as random-access data without some way to index into the data stream. More importantly, even if you could change a single byte without writing the rest of the file, you can't *delete* a byte without writing out the remainder of the file after the deleted text.

Since you didn't specify a language in your original question, I will point you to some Ruby methods that allow for line-oriented, character-oriented, and byte-oriented file manipulation. This will enable you to treat the text as a sequence of characters or bytes without having to slurp the entire file into memory at once.

Consider the difference between the following [Ruby IO methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html):

- IO#read
- IO#readline
- IO#readlines
- IO#readbyte
- IO#readchar

## Some Practical Solutions

### The Simplest Solution: Optimize for Speed Instead of Memory

In general, slurping the entire file into a single string with [File#read](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-read) or creating a multiline array with [File#readlines](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-readlines) will be fastest as long as you have sufficient memory, but memory requirements grow as the size of the input file grows. In short, you're trying to avoid the problem of an unbounded file size with the equivalent of:

```
File.read('file') do |f|
  f.delete '6'
end
```

Unless you have a reasonable expectation of disk thrashing or constrained memory (such as in an embedded system) then doing something other than slurping the file may be a premature optimization. Your mileage may vary.

### Potential Solutions for Memory-Constrained Systems

Assuming that they aren't premature optimizations, you can certainly adapt the following approaches to almost any language. I present them here in Ruby for readability and ease of experimentation.

#### Line-Oriented Approach

One way to handle multiple lines of input with very little memory overhead (assuming your file has newlines, of course) is with [File#readline](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-readline). For example:

```
old_file = File.new 'file'
new_file = File.new 'file.new', 'w'

# Delete the string character '6' from each line of input.
while line = old_file.readline do
  new_file.puts line.delete '6'
end
```

#### Character-Oriented Approach

An even more memory-conservative character-oriented approach might use [File#readchar](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-readchar). For example:

```
old_file = File.new 'file'
new_file = File.new 'file.new', 'w'

# Write each character to the new file unless the character is "6".
while char = old_file.readchar do
  new_file.print(char) unless char == '6'
end
```